# Is there a way to determine the kernel of the map $f: M \to F \otimes M$ defined by $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, principal-ideal-domains

For this problem, suppose that $R$ is a commutative, unital ring. Further, for the sake of ease, suppose it is an integral domain.

Suppose also that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$ moduled, and $F$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Then $F \otimes M$ is naturally an $F$-vector space.

Then there is a cannonical map $f: M \to F \otimes M$ defined by $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x$.

My question is, how might one determine the kernel of the map $f$?

If we suppose that $R$ is a PID, then I believe we can use the structure theorem to show that $ker(f)=Tor(M)$ where $Tor(M)=\{ m \in M | rm=0 \text{ for some }r \in R \}$ is the torsion submodule of $M$.

My question is thus twofold:

1) Is there a way to show the above result without referring to the structure theorem?

2) Is there a result along the same lines for the case where $R$ is not a PID?

Comment: when R is PID，how you show this by structure theorem？there is indeed a way tby direct limit.

Comment: When R is a PID the structure theorem tell us $ M = R^n \oplus T$ where $T$ is the torsion submodule of $M$. Then, it is easy to see that $F \otimes T = 0$, and furthermore since tensor products distribute over direct sums, we get $F \otimes R^n = F^n$ (here we have used $F \otimes R = F$).

Comment: Thus $F \otimes M = F^n$. Thus, for $m \im M$, we expand $m$ as $m = r_1e_1+...+r_ne_n + t$ where the $e_i$ form a basis for the free part of $M$ and $t$ is a torsion element. Then the $1 \otimes e_i$ form a basis for $F \otimes M$. Thus, we may express $1 \otimes m$ in terms of the $1 \otimes e_i$. (By applying the function $f$ above). If the result is zero, then since $1\otimes e_i$ are a basis, it follows that $r_i$ are all zero. Thus $m=t$ is a torsion element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module $F\otimes M$ is just the localization of $M$ with respect to the set $S$ of all nonzero elements of $R$, with the natural map $M\to F\otimes M$ being $m\mapsto\frac{m}{1}$.  The fraction $\frac{m}{1}$ is equal to $0$ in the localization with respect to $S$ iff there is some $s\in S$ such that $sm=0$.  That is, the kernel of $M\to F\otimes M$ is the set of torsion elements of $M$.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it is correct, but I just want to point out to any future readers who were on my position: the two modules are not exactly the same, but merely isomorphic through a canonical isomorphism ($(r/s) \otimes m \to (rm)/s $).

Comment: Furthermore, after some investigation, the fact that the two are isomorphic isn't strictly needed. Just the existence of a homomorphism from $ F \otimes M \to M'$ where $M'$ is the aforementioned localization, that takes $1 \otimes m$ to $m/1$. Then we may take $1 \otimes m = 0$ and apply the homomorphism to this equation and obtain the result.